# How does street view publish API judge the panorama connection that which direction should it linked to if multiple target set on one panorama?

Tags: json, google-api, panoramas, 360-panorama, google-streetview-publish

I have an issue with the connection request in google street view publish API. Both with single and multiple target. If i create single target from source photo

```
{
 "updatePhotoRequests": [
 {
    "updateMask": "connections",
  "  photo": {
     "photoId": {
       "id": "pano_3"
     },
     "connections": [
      {
        "target": {
          "id": "pano_4"
         }
       },
     ]
   }
 }
 ]
}
```

How the above JSON request set Panorama connection to specific direction of the target panorama. 
For e.g if i set a connection from pano_1 north position to pano_2 south position its not set properly. the link arrow show to right direction rather than forward or backward direction. The following image help to understand the problem
[image: Panorama connection image]

In the above image i intended to create connection to go further but its showing the right arrow button rather than forward button.

Also same issue with multiple photos

```
{
          "updatePhotoRequests": [
        {
        "updateMask": "connections",
           "photo": {
            "photoId": {
               "id": "pano_1"
            },
            "connections": [
               {
                   "target": {
                    "id": "pano_2"
                     }
                       },
                       {
                   "target": {
                    "id": "pano_3"
                         }
                       }
                    ]
                    }
               }
            ]
          }
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is.

Comment: @DaImTo The problem is the arrow direction after creating connection. Sorry if the problem was not accurately explain. any way i have updated my question

Comment: @ArunaRajput There is an answer post by abilita. Thats a correct answer. you have to use [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/batchUpdate) in the request url

Comment: @Harish Kumar What is your expected output? I've also observed that the captured photos too close. Based from this [documentation: Tips for creating multiple 360 photos](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7012050?hl=en&ref_topic=6275604) that you must space the photos about two small steps apart (1 m / 3 ft) when indoors and five steps apart (3 m / 10 ft) when outdoors.

Comment: @HarishKumar Have you got any solution for this issue?

Comment: No i still have this issue @ArunaRajput

Comment: @abielita But the same photos i published with panoskin is published perfectly. My expected output is ok just have problem with the forward arrow. As you can see in the image that arrow show for right direction but its taking me to forward (I want to go forward only so the arrow is not correct) How to set connection so that arrow show straight to the connecting point

Comment: @HarishKumar Still you are waiting for the answer or solved the issue??

Comment: @A.R. I have tried the answer published by abielita that the connection should have proper lat, lng and heading. Will figure out once the connection will update on the map.

Comment: @HarishKumar Yeah sure. please update me once you got the proper connection. I tried but still I have also same issue.

Answer (score 0):

@HarishKumar, the direction of the arrow is determined by the lat,lng and heading of each set of 2 panos which are linked. You may check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro#url_parameters#heading) for reference. Think of it as 2 vertices on a plane, you can move them anywhere on the plane or rotate them around their own center, but there's always only one straight line that connects them.

You need to edit the `heading` of each photo that you want to connect. Example, for pano_1 with arrow pointing to right with `heading:90`, your pano_2 should have a `heading:270`. Be noted that you need to edit both pictures. *(I've done this by trial and error.)*

Comment: I have just update the connections heading for both connected pano with your suggested method. Lets see what happen when they update on map.

Comment: you are right abielita we have to take care of latitude, longitute and heading value of each connected pano. Heading sets the panorama north position and if we want to connect second pano to it then it should be locate at the north of first pano in the map am i right? and if you want to connect the second pano to the east position of the first pano then the second pano should be at the east direction in the map.

Comment: @Harish Kumar can you show an example for 4 pano. Connection as in 1-2,3 & 3-4 so what should be the latitude, longitude and heading each of connected panos?

Comment: @HarishKumar, yes. You should always consider the lat, long and heading of each photos to be connected. Otherwise, it will point to other directions.